# How do I prevent the screen from going blank only during certain hours of the day?

Tags: raspbian, display, screen, debian, screen-saver

I am running Debian on my Pi and I'm using it for a magic mirror. I originally wanted to just prevent the screen from being blank after 10 minutes and keep it on 24/7.
So I opened `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and added `xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms` which did the trick.

The issue now is that the backlight from the monitor is too bright during the nighttime, and it would be more optimal if I could have it running from 6:00am to 11pm. Is there any method that can disable the screen from turning off only during a certain time frame? Thanks!

Comment: What type of screen and how is it connected to the Pi?

Comment: It's a standard computer monitor that's connected with VGA cables.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle HDMI-output on/off with a cron-job triggered at 6:00am and 11:00pm.

Info about the command to run at these times are located here:
https://glframebuffer.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/raspberrypi-how-to-turn-off-hdmi-from-raspberry-pi/

When the HDMI-output is turned off, your monitor will eventually go into power-saving mode and turn off the screen backlight. When HDMI-output is turned on, the monitor will resume back to normal operating mode.